Extracting coefficients from falling factorial form in Mathematica
I have a polynomial in falling factorial form, i. e.
$-x+7(-1+x)x+6(-2+x)(-1+x)x+(-3+x)(-2+x)(-1+x)x$.
Now i want to extract the "outermost" coefficients $\{-1,7,6,1\}$. I have this code to get all the digits next to a left bracket:
numbersNextToLeftBracket = Cases[fallingFactorialForm, a_?(NumberQ) (b_) :> a, {1}]

However, this only gives me $\{-1,7,6\}$ because the last $1$ is not visible. How can I rewrite this so it includes all these coefficients?

This may be better suited to the Mathematica SE.

Based on the FullForm[fallingFactorialForm], for the Cases pattern, try t :(Times[coef_Integer, __] | Times[coef_Plus, __]) :> If[IntegerQ[coef], coef, 1]

Perfect, thank you!

I'm sure there's an edge case that that code does not address. If you want to be careful, you should check in with the gurus at the Mma SE.
